# Order an array by date in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony 3 project.  I am getting an array from it, which I want to order by date.  However when I try to do this using the following:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('cats');
        $catRepo = $entityManager->getRepository("CatsBundle:cat");
        $items = $catRepo->findBy([],['entry_date' => 'ASC']);
```

It says:

```
Unrecognized field: entry_date
```

The entry_date field is a DateTime object.  When I sort by fields that are strings it works fine, but not with DateTimes.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to add a property `entryDate`

```
private $entryDate;
```

then replace

```
$items = $catRepo->findBy([],['entry_date' => 'ASC']);
```

for

```
$items = $catRepo->findBy([],['entryDate' => 'ASC']);
```